# Пропал скрол в visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу понять что произошло, но во всех проектах пропал скроллинг листа горизонтальный и вертикальный. Длина листа большая. Прошу подсказать что не так.
[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте включен ли у вас скролл в настройках

**Tools-> Options**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверил, все включено. Заметил что скролов нет только в файлах с кодом, в конструкторе скролл есть.

Answer (score 1):

решил такую же проблему удалением каталога %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: Спасибо! Я ее решил переустановкой)